# C# Console Output

Tags: c#, console

Is it possible to control/write to a console from another. I have tested the Console.WriteLine, but nothing happend. I appreciate any help.

---

I meant write to a console from another **class**. Sorry for the misleading.
I have a server class (Server.cs) and the main class (Program.cs). The server class is going to write some info about connection, and stuff like that, to the console.

Comment: I believe _if_ it can be done(which I believe it can't), it's with win32API.

Comment: are you looking for console redirection  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx

Comment: @corn3lius. Console isn't a `TextReader`. And it's static so how would you pass it's reference? **...**

Comment: Do you have control of the source code of the "other" console window? If so, you may be able to DuplicateHandle the console handle (GetStdHandle) and send it to the controlling program using some form of interprocess communication. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to clarify the question a bit. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a console application that i have programmed to act as a server. One class (Server.cs) listens for a client. This class is going to output some text to the console. But I also have the Program.cs class. How can the server class output text to the console?

Comment: In the first question I meant write to a console from another class. Sorry for the misleading.

Answer (score 1):

To write to the calling console, your application needs to be marked as a `Console` application in project settings. If you write to the console in a UI application, your process will create a new one and then write in it.

If you want to write to another existing console, I guess it could be possible using P-Invoke on the Win32Api functions such as `AttachConsole`, `WriteConsole` and `FreeConsole`.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistake, you want something like this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

p.StartInfo.FileName = "ModelExporter.exe";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();

StreamReader myStreamReader = p.StandardOutput;

// Reads a single line of the programs output.
string myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine(); 

// This would print the string to the DOS Console for the sake of an example.
// You could easily set a textbox control to this string instead...
Console.WriteLine(myString);

p.Close();
```